# IndexError: Invalid Index for Scalar Variable NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library, index-error

So I tried to convert an image to an array with PIL and NumPy. Then I tried to iterate through a file and get all the images from it and then see how many red, green and blue pixels it has to see what is the main color of the image and I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import time
from PIL import Image


def load_image(image: str):
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.load()
    return img


def image_to_array(image):
    array_img = np.asarray(image, dtype="int32")
    return array_img


def get_image_color(image):
    img = load_image(image)
    img_array = image_to_array(img)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    red = 0
    green = 0
    blue = 0
    for i in img_array:
        for j in i:
            if j[0] != j[1] != j[2]:
                if j[0] > j[1] and j[0] > j[2]:
                    red += 1
                elif j[1] > j[0] and j[1] > j[2]:
                    green += 1
                elif j[2] > j[0] and j[2] > j[1]:
                    blue += 1

    if red > green and red > blue:
        return "Red Image"
    elif green > red and green > blue:
        return "Green Image"
    elif blue > red and blue > green:
        return "Blue Image"


def get_all_images(path: str):
    images = os.listdir(path)
    return images

PATH = "File's Path here"

red_images = get_all_images(f"{PATH}\\Red_Images\\")
green_images = get_all_images(f"{PATH}\\Green_Images\\")
blue_images = get_all_images(f"{PATH}\\Blue_Images\\")

for red_img in red_images:
    print(red_img)
    print(f"Picture: {red_img.split('.')[0]} =", get_image_color(f"{PATH}\\Red_Images\\{red_img}"))
```

When I run it through the `for` loop it detects the first image but the second image throughs an Index error

This is the output:

```
    red_image1.jpg
    Picture: red_image1 = Red Image
    red_image2.jpg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "ADD_PATH_HERE/color_from_image.py", line 57, in <module>
        print(f"Picture: {red_img.split('.')[0]} =", get_image_color(f" 
   {PATH}\\Red_Images\\{red_img}"))
      File "ADD_PATH_HERE/color_from_image.py", line 27, in get_image_color
        if j[0] > j[1] and j[0] > j[2]:
    IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Comment: You forgot the output ;) And in which for loop?

Comment: in the for loop that iterates through the red_images list

Comment: As a general hint: Use HSV color space instead of RGB/BGR, that makes things usually much easier, if you are analyzing colors ;)

Comment: So what have you tried? Have you printed the size of your array for example? Can you narrow down why the error occurs? Oh and something else: What happens if by chance your image has as many red, as green, as blue pixels?

Comment: So if all the pixels are the same number it will probably print "Red Image", because that is the first color that is checked, but my problem is that, when the code runs once, it detects the image's color just fine, but when it iterates to the second image it throws and IndexError

Comment: _"So what have you tried? Have you printed the size of your array for example? Can you narrow down why the error occurs?"_? And no, it will not print anything, since red is not bigger than green or blue, blue is not bigger than red or green and green is not bigger than red or blue.

Comment: I'm not bothered if an image has the same number of different colored pixels, I would have added that option later but I got stuck on this error.

Comment: I just run it again and printed `j` before the IndexError and it output `1`

Comment: For the third time: __"So what have you tried? Have you printed the size of your array for example? Can you narrow down why the error occurs?"?__ Without information about your images we cannot help you. Since it runs through once it probably is a problem with the image itself.

Comment: In the first iteration it printed every array of the `img_array` and in the second iteration it printed `1` :(

Comment: I have tried your code with some pictures on my computer and it runs perfectly fine, something is wrong with your second image. Could you add a `print(img_array)` before the for loop?

Comment: Runned it again without the `red_image2.jpg`. The first iteration it printed every pixel of the first image(`red_image1.jpg`). Second iteration and it worked just fine, printed every pixel of `red_image3.jpg`.

Comment: I don't understand why that is because all 3 images where .jpg

Comment: What's the shape of `img_array`?  When it runs I suspect it is 3d with 3 channel color.  But it may be 2d with a bw image, and produce this error.

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize it in an answer:
With the following code I have no problem running it:

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import time
from PIL import Image


def load_image(image: str):
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.load()
    return img


def image_to_array(image):
    array_img = np.asarray(image, dtype="int32")
    return array_img


def get_image_color(image):
    img = load_image(image)
    img_array = image_to_array(img)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    red = 0
    green = 0
    blue = 0
    for i in img_array:
        for j in i:
            if j[0] != j[1] != j[2]:
                if j[0] > j[1] and j[0] > j[2]:
                    red += 1
                elif j[1] > j[0] and j[1] > j[2]:
                    green += 1
                elif j[2] > j[0] and j[2] > j[1]:
                    blue += 1

    if red > green and red > blue:
        return "Red Image"
    elif green > red and green > blue:
        return "Green Image"
    elif blue > red and blue > green:
        return "Blue Image"


def get_all_images(path: str):
    images = os.listdir(path)
    return images

PATH = "File's Path here"

red_images = get_all_images("/home/user/Pictures/")

for red_img in red_images:
    print(red_img)
    print(f"Picture: {red_img.split('.')[0]} =", get_image_color(f"/home/user/Pictures/{red_img}"))
```

The problem seems to be in your second picture. Maybe wrong format, since you load them as `dtype="int32"`. But the code is correct.

Comment: This is the output of the second image I tried to use:

    [[1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]
     [1 4 2 ... 2 4 1]
     [1 2 5 ... 5 2 1]
     ...
     [1 2 5 ... 5 2 1]
     [1 4 2 ... 2 4 1]
     [1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]]

And then an IndexError

Comment: This is the image I used: [red_image2.jpg](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiTgp2RopjnAhUOEVAKHQO7CGwQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fimgur.com%2Fgallery%2FXnfn5Jm&psig=AOvVaw06vKBdlq0XzotMDgG76xHy&ust=1579818889087492)

Comment: Seeing the output you can see, that it is only  a 2D image, so without any colour channel, this means, that `j` is an integer, not an array which you can access with `j[0]` or similar. I don't know why it is a 2D image try to show the image in the `load_image(image)` function and see, if it is black-white or coloured